# find the first several roots of a function

Tags: equation-solving

I have a function like this:

[image]

How to find the first several roots (that is larger than 0) of it?

Using `FindRoot`, it's difficult to localize to the root I want.

Comment: If the linked thread does not suit your needs, edit your question to explain why.